# how to clear the session and token of google id,so as to login again

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my application,i can login to google+ and get the data,but when i click on logout,and then click on login again,it display data of prevoius login id,but i want after logout,on login it again ask the login id and password,as all login requires. please suggest somthing.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess,post;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signout);
        post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postToWall);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);


        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
        post.setOnClickListener(this);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {

            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {

                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }







    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        getProfileInformation();

         updateUI(true);

    }


    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signin:

            signInWithGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.signout:

            signOutFromGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.postToWall:

            shareOnGooglePlus(this, "caption");
            break;
      case R.id.revoke:

            revokeGplusAccess();
            break;
        }
    }


    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }


    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to Revoke The Access From Google, Add below Code in your Sign Out Method. and than Connect to GoogleApiClient inside onResult , in your Code you Are only  Disconneting From Google Api Client .

```
 Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(googleApiClient)
                 .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                     }

                 });
```

Complete Code here :

```
 private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(googleApiClient)
                 .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                          updateUI(false);
                     }

                 });
    }
}
```